# Image feature extraction in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

```py
Allsample_point=Forest_sample_point.merge(NonForest_sample_point).merge(Water_sample_point);

###Export sample points
geemap.ee_to_shp(Allsample_point, filename='Allsample_point.shp', selectors=None)

###load sample points
point_path =r'D:\GEE_GEEMAP\Allsample_point.shp'
Allsample_point=geemap.shp_to_ee(point_path)

##feature extraction
Allsample_point= extract_image.sampleRegions(
    collection=Allsample_point,
    scale=10,
    geometries=True
)
```

`Allsample_point` is my sample point. If I do not export and load the sample point to extract features, the calculation will time out.

However, the import and export operations belong to client functions, and cannot be written in parallel in the map() function later.

Do you have any good suggestions?